# Center IMG on Nav Bar

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to center our IMG on our nav bar.  Apologies this is such a basic question.

Text align doesn't work and the following doesn't work bc it makes the img go above the nav bar list.  Anyone have any ideas on the simplest fix?  Many Thanks!

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto }
```

```css
.logo img {
  width: 34%;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  height: 35%;
}
.nav-item--left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item--left {
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
}
.nav-item--right:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-item--right {
  display: block;
}
.nav-item--right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item--right {
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
}
.nav-item--right:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.nav-item--right {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="narrow-display-test" style="display:none"></div>

<header class="header container container--fluid container--darkBackground js-header">


  <div class="container">
    <a href="/" class="logo">
      <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" alt="alt">
    </a>




    <ul class="nav">



      <li class="nav-item">

        <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link">
          <div class="header" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="welcome pull-right" ng-show="userLoaded">
                <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link" href="">
                  <span ng-show="currentUser">Your Site</span>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>





      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link">
          <div class="header" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="welcome pull-right" ng-show="userLoaded">
                <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link" href="/">
                  <span ng-show="currentUser">Your Site2 </span>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>




      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link">
          <div class="header" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="welcome pull-right" ng-show="userLoaded">
                <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link" href="/">
                  <span ng-hide="currentUser">
    Your Site 3
    </span>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link">
          <div class="header" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="welcome pull-right" ng-show="userLoaded">
                <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link" href="/">
                  <span ng-hide="currentUser">
    Your Site 4
    </span>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link">
          <div class="header" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="welcome pull-right" ng-show="userLoaded">
                <a class="nav-itemText nav-itemText--link">

                  <ng-include src="'/partials/login.html'"></ng-include>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly and add your html also

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, it's updated! @hello

Comment: Sorry, it's updated! @Pushpendra

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard code in padding and margin to center an element, using auto margin is the common solution.

Typically issues with elements not showing up where they should comes from using the `float` attribute.  Using float takes the element out of the normal flow of the DOM. You need to clear the float for elements to take their normal positions after a floated element.

Here's an article that helps explain more about floats:

https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Again, this is all assuming your issue comes from floats.

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggesting any improvements.

Comment: @Pushpendra I submitted it too early.  I was still writing up my answer. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple trick you can use.

Make your image become a child of a navbar then set `position:relative;` to the navbar.

Now in your image insert this code.

```
img{
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The image will go to the very center of your navbar both vertical and horizontal.

But if you only want to center it horizontally, remove the `top: 50%;` and change the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Like this:

```
img{
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```

And for vertical, remove the `left: 50%;` and change the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to `transform: translateY(-50%);`

Like this:

```
img{
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `div` with class `row text-center` above image link as below:

```
  <div class="row text-center">
    <a href="/" class="logo">
      <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" alt="alt">
    </a>
  </div>
```